# ANOVA Table With A Dynamic Input In R Shiny

Tags: shiny

I am trying to make a Shiny app that outputs an ANOVA table based on a dynamic numeric variable input from the `iris` dataset.

This is the part where I am struggling:
`aov.model <- aov(input$varNames ~ iris$Species, data = iris)`

The above works if I replace the dynamic input part to any of the specified variable names:

`aov.model <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)`

How should I deal with the dynamic input part `input$varNames` ?

Here is the fully working code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("ANOVA",
             uiOutput("varNames"),
             verbatimTextOutput("anovaTable")
    )
  )
)

# @
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$varNames <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("varNames2",
                   "Variables: ",
                   choices = names(iris[, -5])
    )
  })
  
  output$anovaTable <- renderPrint({
    aov.model <- aov(input$varNames ~ iris$Species, data = iris) # Stuck here
    print(aov.model)
    br()
    br()
    print(summary(aov.model))
    cat("Coefficients"); cat("\n")
    print(aov.model$coefficients)
  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have `varNames`.  It should be `input$varNames2`.  Also, you should call it as

```
aov.model <- aov(iris[[input$varNames2]] ~ iris$Species, data = iris)
```

Then you get the following output:

[image: output]